# Can I add some more columns then the data in parquet file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet

I can use COPY command to import the content of a parquet file to redshift, but I would like to also add some more columns, like the time that the data inserted, and also the path of the parquet file, how can I do that?

Comment: Looks unlikely. Here's a similar question from a while ago. No evidence that it has since changed: [Redshift add column when importing with COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27336070/174777)

Comment: However, it seems like it _could_ be possible if you read the files using Redshift Spectrum instead: [AWS Redshift Spectrum - how to get the s3 filenames in the external table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666659/174777) There is a `$path` variable, but that seems to only provide the Prefix, not the Key.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it provides the full key

Answer (score 1):

Use spectrum to import it, you get “$path” as a pseudo column, which is the full s3 url of the file it’s in. You don’t get the timestamp of the s3 file though.